# Pasting Data from One Column to Other Using Conditional If for Value?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a real newb to to VBA and slowly learning. I've been wrecking my head over something that seems so simple but can't seem to figure it out as I've tried different ways of searching on google.

I would like to make a macro that takes on range of cells and copies it into another range of cells if the value of another column is greater than zero.

The code I used is:

```
    Sub Carry()
If Range("E6:E14").Value > 0 Then

Range("F6:F14").Copy
Range("G6:G14").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End If

End Sub
```

Picture of the columns

Picture of what I mean.

[image]

Comment: Try this: `Sub Carry(): With Range("G6:G14"): .Formula = "=IF(E6>0,F6,"""")": .Value = .Value: End With: End Sub`.

Comment: You do know that one doesn't need VBA to put a formula in the cells... just put the formula above =IF(E6>0, F6, "") in G6 and drag down...